# php initialize if not set

Tags: php, associative-array

I find myself doing the following quite a bit:

```
if (isset($objs[$key]){
    $objs[$key] += val;
} else {
    $objs[$key] = $val;
}
```

Is there a better way to do that?
Another way could be:

```
$objs[$key] = isset($objs[$key]) ? $objs[$key] + $val : $val
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I just found a very related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308835/is-it-good-practice-to-initialize-the-elements-in-an-associative-array-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to simplify could be a function taking the array by reference and deduplicate the code.

If you are using php 7  you can also make use the new `??` operator (assuming all values are integers):

```
$arr[$key] = ($arr[$key] ?? 0) + $value;
```

However, if you know the shape of the array you should base your actions on that. Create the array using array_fill_keys or similiar in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are always adding numbers... you could do something like this to keep a single line of code for each entry which may or may not be preferable for you to your existing solution.

```
$objs = array();

addvalue($objs, "dog", 2);
addvalue($objs, "dog", 5);
// $objs['dog'] will = 7

function addvalue(& $var, $key, $value){
    if (isset($var[$key])){
        $var[$key] += $value;
    } else {
        $var[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```